# Vertical align 3 divs with inline-block

Tags: html, css, intel-xdk

I can't make vertical align all 3 divs inside this li. I have tried inside a div too, but nothing. What can I do?

```
<li style="list-style:none;border-bottom:1px solid white;height:60px;background-color:blue;padding-left:5%;padding-right:5%">
  <div style="max-width:39%;min-width:39%;display:inline-block;;vertical-align:middle;text-align:right">
    Equipo 1
  </div> 
  <div style="max-width:19%;min-width:19%;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;text-align:center">
    18/05<br>12:30
  </div> 
  <div style="max-width: 38%;min-width: 38%;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle">
    Equipo 2
  </div>
</li>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/526TD/)

Thanks

Comment: Do you want them one below the other? Because as I can see in the demo, vertical align is working properly

Comment: Would you like one div on top of another?

Comment: I want vertical align of the parent element. The 3 divs ara aligned, but not in the middle of li.

Comment: your markup makes no sense. there is an `li` element without a `ul' parent...

Comment: you should read about html markup first, `li` without `ul` or `ol` makes no sense and block elements like `div`s are not allowed in `li`s  as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need one of the inline-box to fit the height of parent, so others will vertical-align aside it.

You may use a pseudo element to generate this element wich will be used as reference to vertical-align: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/526TD/4/)**

```
li:before {
    content:'';
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

`<edit>` [playground pen for line-height](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/rmxpo)`</edit>`

Comment: Oki, hope you understood how vertical-align works :)

Comment: Not enterily. I have tried set on the 3 divs elements height:100%. Than they had the same height as li, but vertical align didn't work. Can you give a link to understand this function with pseudo element? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Gaucho_9 i do not have a link at this time, but vertical-align applied on inline-boxes needs 2 boxes or 1 box and a line-height . one boxe + line-height, vertical-align will take line-height as reference to adjust the box alignement value. 2 boxes , values on both boxes (can be different will adjust to height of each others and will still mind the line-height if set heigher than the the higest boxe. here a test page to play with : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bLaEu